# Trying to understand classes in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, class

I'm working on my first real Flex app and i have learned a lot by it. Now I'm trying to understand the basics of working with classes. I have a function that asks information from the LastFm API. This is the base function:

```
        public function zoekChart(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var api_URL:String = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/';
            var api_method:String = 'geo.getMetroUniqueArtistChart';
            var api_key:String = '99f1f497c0bd598f1ec20571a38e2219';
            var country:String = countryText.text;
            var metro:String = metroText.text;
            var limit:String = '5'; 
            api_request = api_URL + '?method=' + api_method + '&country=' + country + '&metro=' + metro + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=' + limit;
            myRequest.send();
        }
```

Now I'm trying to make a class which does the same as the function. This is what i have so far:

```
package valueObjects
{
public class Kevin_myChart
{
    private var api_URL:String;
    private var api_method:String;
    private var api_key:String;
    private var country:String;
    private var metro:String;
    private var limit:String;

        public function lastFMCall (api_URL:String, api_method:String, api_key:String, 
                                     country:String, metro:String, limit:String) 
        {
            this.api_URL=api_URL;
            this.api_method=api_method;
            this.api_key=api_key;
            this.country=country;
            this.metro=metro;
            this.limit=limit;
        }

        public function getInfo(size:String):String 
        {

            return api_URL + '?method=' + api_method + '&country=' + country + '&metro=' + metro + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=' + limit;

        }   
}
```

}

Is this a good start? My first question is how i can import the values of textfields countryText and metroText in the class.

Also, how should I continue from here? How can i make sure that my application will be able to use the functions declared in the class and how can i get values in the class's vars now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your class's `constructor` to pass the values. A constructor is called when you create a new instance of your class.

```
public function zoekChart(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var api_URL:String = 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/';
    var api_method:String = 'geo.getMetroUniqueArtistChart';
    var api_key:String = '99f1f497c0bd598f1ec20571a38e2219';
    var country:String = countryText.text;
    var metro:String = metroText.text;
    var limit:String = '5'; 

    // create a new instance of your class
    var kevinMyChart:Kevin_myChart = new Kevin_myChart(api_URL, api_method, api_key:, country, metro, limit);

    // not sure what the 'size' is used for
    api_request = kevinMyChart.getInfo("size");
    myRequest.send();
}
```

Your `Kevin_myChart` class with constructor:

```
package valueObjects
{
    public class Kevin_myChart
    {
        private var api_URL:String;
        private var api_method:String;
        private var api_key:String;
        private var country:String;
        private var metro:String;
        private var limit:String;

        public function Kevin_myChart(api_URL:String, api_method:String, api_key:String, country:String, metro:String, limit:String) 
        {
            this.api_URL=api_URL;
            this.api_method=api_method;
            this.api_key=api_key;
            this.country=country;
            this.metro=metro;
            this.limit=limit;
        }

        public function getInfo(size:String) : String 
        {
            // not sure what the 'size' is used for    
            return api_URL + '?method=' + api_method + '&country=' + country + '&metro=' + metro + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=' + limit;

        }   
    }
}
```

Your getting in the right direction, maybe this tutorial will give you some more info about the way a class is build.

http://www.kirupa.com/developer/as3/classes_as3_pg3.htm

Otherwise a quick [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20work%20with%20classes%20in%20as3) could help you further aswell.

Comment: Thanks for your great reply. It's really late here, so i'm going to wait til tomorrow to try it out, but i'll be sure to let you know if it worked and mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: Bedankt :) I tried to implement the code, but i got 2 errors -> var kevinMyChart:Kevin_myChart = new Kevin_myChart(api_URL, api_method, api_key, country, metro, limit); incorrect number of arguments, expected 0. And  api_request = kevinMyChart.getInfo; implicit coercion type function to unrelated type string. Also, the 'size' can be deleted, i was trying something and forgot to delete that.

Comment: Edit: i fixed the first error, i'll try to fix the 2nd one too. but any help is welcome!

Comment: Ah, the 2nd error is beacause you're referencing the method itself. `kevinMyChart.getInfo` returns the function. Rewrite it to `kevinMyChart.getInfo()` will make it execute the method. If you want it to be a property you can write a 'getter' in your class like so: `public function get getInfo():String { return ''; }`. This will make it possible to call `kevinMyChart.getInfo` and get the String.

Comment: Thanks it works :) I'm going to try and extend the class a bit with a getter etc. But i now understand the functions of a class. Thanks!